# How to observe UITextfield.selectedTextRange?

Tags: swift, xcode, range, uitextfield, nsnotificationcenter

How to create an event when UITextfield.selectedTextRange was changed?

I did not found any delegate method for that. Maybe I can create custom observer somehow? I cannot figure out how to do that.

The goal is to trigger some method when selectedTextRange in UITextfield was changed and get a pointer to that UITextfield also to work with target text field inside.

I've tried to override selectedTextRange but it's being triggered in real time many times while dragging cursor. And method triggered is heavy enough to cause UI slow down when triggered 100 times per second.

Answer (score 1):

**For >= iOS 13**

You can accomplish this by implementing the `textFieldDidChangeSelection:` function with declaring a local variable that will store the most recent selected text range of a TextField. You need to store the last selection so you get notified only by new selection, and not by other changes of the TextField(for example by typing).

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
   private var lastSelectedText = ""
   // Rest of your MyViewController code 

}

extension MyViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if let textRange = textField.selectedTextRange, let selectedText = textField.text(in: textRange), selectedText != lastSelectedText {
            lastSelectedText = selectedText
            // Handle change of selectedText or selectedTextRange 
        }
    }
}
```

**For iOS 12 >=**

As you mentioned you can override the `selectedTextRange` property of the UITextField. I just tested it and it works smooth for every cursor change.

```
class MyTextField: UITextField {
    override var selectedTextRange: UITextRange? {
        get {return super.selectedTextRange}
        set {
            // Handle newValue here
            super.selectedTextRange = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, textFieldDidChangeSelection is what I was looking for!
But I have a question. How to skip an action while I am dragging the cursor (either by dragging inside the text field OR dragging on the keyboard when it transforms to touchpad)

Comment: When you store the last value in a local variable, may call it lastSelectedText as it is above, and compare the new value with the old value and do an action only if they don't match, should not fire when you are just dragging the cursor.

Comment: Yep, understand that but we have another problem. Value is changing every time cursor appears between another characters while still dragging, with the new value each time. So if 10 symbols string, method will be fired 10 times from the right to the left, and if you drag fast left-right-left-right it fires just very often and a lot with new value each time...